# HTTP Status [400] – [Bad Request] — Required Integer parameter 'id' is not present

Tags: java, json, rest, soapui

REST-метод:

```
@PostMapping
public void createOrUpdate(@RequestParam("id") Integer id,
                           @RequestParam("dateTime") LocalDateTime dateTime,
                           @RequestParam("description") String description,
                           @RequestParam("calories") int calories) {
    Meal meal = new Meal(id, dateTime, description, calories);
    if (meal.isNew()) {
        super.create(meal);
    } else {
        super.update(meal, id);
    }
}
```

POST-запрос из SoapUI через JSON:

```
{
   "id": null,
   "dateTime": "2015-05-31T21:00:00",
   "description": "Ужин2",
   "calories": 540,
   "user": null
}
```

Путь запроса верный, работает на других методах. Авторизация учитывается.
Почему-то выбрасывает ошибку 400:

```
00:02:26.105 DEBUG o.s.w.s.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException:133 - Resolving exception from handler [public void ru.javawebinar.topjava.web.meal.MealAjaxController.createOrUpdate(java.lang.Integer,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.lang.String,int)]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Integer parameter 'id' is not present
```

> Type Status Report
>
> Message Required Integer parameter 'id' is not present
>
> Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to
>   something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed
>   request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request
>   routing).

Не могу понять, что не так. `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` добавлял, толку нет.

Comment: @RequestParam("id") Integer id регистрирует обязательный параметр id, в запросе приходил nul, вот и ошибка

Comment: вводил и реальный id — ошибка остаётся. вероятно, POST-запрос нужно принимать не через JSON?

Comment: А точно передаешь Integer, а не int к примеру? Плюс скинь стек когда указываешь все параметры, если один параметр не передан, будет сваливаться в 400 ошибку, если конечно ты не предусмотрел этот вариант.

Comment: Ты ж видишь, что передаю. Менял null на 100007, результат тот же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что JSON не проходит через POST-запрос.
Для выполнения POST-запроса из SoapUI нужно вписать данные в параметры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]